# Flutter showDialog with loading spinner and confirmation

Tags: flutter, showdialog

In flutter, I have a showDialog() with cancel and confirm button. The confirm button will trigger a call to an API. What I need is to show a "loading..." in the showDialog window after the click and once the API call is finished to show a success or failure. How can I manage this? Or should I close the window, waiting for the reply and popup a new dialog window with success or false? Thx for any help or better suggestion. Here what I have so far:

```
void _showAlert(String textLabel, String action, String linkId) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    //barrierDismissible: false, // on external click
    builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
      title: new Text(
        'Please confirm:',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      content: new Text(
        textLabel,
        style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: new Text('CANCEL')),
        new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _postAction(action, linkId).then((_) => setState(() {}));
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: new Text('I CONFIRM')),
      ],
    ));
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/huangjianke/flutter_easyloading

Comment: thx, but it should happen in the dialog window

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,this is just the idea..

```
class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {

  bool isSuccessFromApi = false;
  bool isLoading = false;

  Widget popup() {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (builder) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: !isSuccessFromApi ? Container(
          child: Text('Are you Sure???'),
        ) : Container( child: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : Text('Success'),),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Text('Cancel'),
          InkWell(child: Text('OK'), onTap: apiCall,)
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  void apiCall(){
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    //call the api
    //after success or failure
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      isSuccessFromApi = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: popup(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your tip, but it seems not working. I put a print before the AlertDialog in order to check variable isLoading. The variable does not change when the API is called. Seems like the setState is not rebuilding the dialog window. I found a link (https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/05/hint-5-how-to-refresh-the-content-of-a-dialog-via-setstate/) which also explains this issue

Comment: Then you have to add a separate widget for that alert